# Permission to Start activity denied Restarting appium server not helping

Tags: java, appium

When i am running this script in TestNG

```
`package TrainingDay3;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

public class Test1 {

    private static WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeClass

  public void beforeClass() {

      //public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

            File file = new File("D:\\workspace\\AppiumTraining\\apk\\app-qa-debug_original.apk");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("Version", "6.0.1");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "XT-1254");
            capabilities.setCapability("app", file.getAbsolutePath());
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "org.aarp.careconnect");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "org.aarp.careconnect.activities.MainActivity");
            try {
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

  }

        @Test
          public void f() {

            //locate the Text on the app by using By.className()
                    //driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.Button")).click();//("android.widget.Button")).click();
                    //driver.findElement(By.className("android.view.View")).click();
                    //driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).click();
                    //driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.Button")).click();

          }

  @AfterClass
  public void afterClass() {
            // TODO: handle exception
            //close the app
            driver.quit();
  }
}`
```

getting exception FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass beforeClass
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Permission to start activity denied.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700' although i have  restarted the appium server multiple times but it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You are launching activity which has android exported = True

To solve this issue, follow below steps:

- Set path for SDK/build-tools
- Now from command prompt run aapt dumb badging "path of apk"
- Find Launchable activity

This will work